# PanacheMongo find with wildcard

Tags: mongodb, wildcard, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am trying to do a simple `find` in Panache but I'm stuck with the wildcard operator.

I have:

```
Model.find("payload.tags.name = ?1", "tag-to")
    .stream()
    .map(m -> (Model) m)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and my document looks something like this:

```
{
...
payload:Object{
    swagger:"2.0"
    info:Object
    host:"petstore.swagger.io"
    basePath:"/v2"
    tags:Array[
        0:Object [
            name:"tag-to-find"
            description:"a tag i want to find"
        ]
    ]

}
}
```

When I try to find "tag-to-find" it works, but I don't know how to get the wildcards going. In mongoshell i just use `db.Model.find({"payload.tags.name": /ag-to-/})` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using in Mongo shell is a JavaScript regex.
You should also be able to use it with MongoDB with Panache.

You should normaly use the regex with the `$regex` operator, not sure how Mongo shell handle it but the following should work:

```
Model.list("payload.tags.name like ?1", "/tag-to/")
```

I use `.list()` instead of `find()` as it directly return the list of documents.

The query used here is what we called *PanacheQL* query that will maps to a MongoDB native query, you can also use a native query directly (with named or indexed parameters).

Simplified query is explained here: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#simplified-queries

Comment: I had this guide open for the last days and I seem to always have scrolled over the examples... thanks a lot! 
Unfortunately it's very hard sometimes to google for panache related questions, so thank you for your elaborate answer!